# How to blur reflection of HDRI on glass object

Tags: hdri

I have this object with glass shader. I enabled HDRI and pumped it a lot, so it can light my scene. However, now you can clearly see  every reflection of objects around, those letters on the left and so on. How can I blur those reflections so you can't clearly see like it's mirror, not glass, but leave all lighting it produces.

[image]

Comment: you could change the Roughness value, or blur the image in an image editor like Krita or Photoshop

Comment: @moonboots Blurring in photoshop would be tidious because I want to export 140 frames.. not sure how much time would it take. :/

Comment: I meant you can blur the hdri image

Comment: Oh, that is something I could do. Gonna try it. Thanks

Comment: @Emir tried but don't get nowhere near result

Comment: @moonboots Blurring HDRI in photoshop helped! Thanks a lot